# Add source to all contacts when importing a CSV File

Tags: contacts, import, addresses

Question in German

> Wir möchten eine CSV Datei mit Kontakten einer Gruppe hinzufügen. Dies ging auch mühelos.Das einzige das nicht funktioniert hat war diese neue Adressen die Bezugsquelle hinzu zu fügen.
>   Wie geht das.

Translated

> We want to import a CSV file with contacts in a group. Well, we accompished this easily. The only thing we miss is that we add to this new addresses the source of the visitors. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you importing contacts or activities? When importing contacts you can use *Contact Source*.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'the source of the visitors'? If you want to set the source of a contact you can use Contact Source as Karin Urban suggested, but it sounds as if you want a source for an address? And please can you mention which version of CiviCRM you are using with which CMS? That will help you to get answers :-)